# Android DrawerLayout must be declared Error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, android-support-library

I am making a simple Android app and I wanted to make a DrawerLayout menu. When I went to use it, it said that drawer layout must be declared. I checked my SDK manager and the android support jar is installed and up to date.
[image]
I tried uninstalling and re-installing but that did not help. I also tried creating a new project and that did not work.

Code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Error:

```
Element android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout must be declared
```

**Other Info:**
Minimum API: 7
Build API: 18
IDE: Android Studio*(Using Gradle)*

Android Studio Build Number: AI-132.863010*(Up to date)*
**I am now using Android studio 3.0**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the support library to your libraries.

**If you are using Gradle, just add:**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
}
```

to your `build.gradle` file.

**If not using gradle to take care of your dependencies:**
Press Ctrl + Alt- Shift +S ([image: Project Structure Icon]Project Structure).

**Then Libraries > New Project Library > Java**

Locate the JAR I am sure you copied to your ./libs folder already and you should be done.
**or use this shortcut:**
just copy android-support-v4.jar to YourProject/libs, right click on the JAR from Android Studio and choose *Add as Library*

**Edit:**
As of Android Studio 0.3 You shouldn't have to manually edit the gradle file, you can just add the libraries in project structure.